# Extending Margins on WordPress CSS

Tags: css

I'm using a WordPress hosted site and my main concern is that the margins aren't as I'd like them to be. I'm not sure how I can express what I mean here, but I'll give it a shot.

This is the **homepage with blog posts:**

```
                                Blog title, 
                                Blog body is this,
                                continues here... I just
                                need to increase the right 
                                margin.
```

Again, it isn't **that much** to the right as it's displayed here -- it's even placed, I'd just like to extend the right margin, rather. which part of the code with that be in? Should I update it with the code?

**Update**

Is it this code?

```
    }
    .entry-content {
        overflow: hidden;
        zoom:1;
    }
    /* Sidebar
```

or this?

```
}
h3, #sidebar, .postdata, .entry-content {
    font-family:'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of hard to know without more proper technical info (html and css code).
I'm guessing here you should look for **entry-content** class in the style.css file of your theme directory and add the margin you desire.

If you can't find the class there, just add it at the end of the css file:

```
.entry-content{
   margin-right:100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually found two matches, which one is it? I updated the question.

Comment: first one, just add the **margin-right:777px;** there. Or... you may add the piece of css I told you at the end of the file. That way you know that all of your custom changes are located at the end of the file (in case you need to make more in the future)

Comment: I tried adding it to the end like you mentioned but nothing seemed to work. I'll try to insert it to the first code which you said was correct. Where do I add it, though? Below /Sidebar text? Above?

Comment: Insert it just below zoom:1; ... but it the first attempt didn't work, i'm afraid that this property is being rewritten by another css (or maybe this isn't the container you need :( ). Instead of **margin-right:777px;** insert **margin-right:777px !important;** It's kind of evil, but let's give it a try. If nothing seems to work, please make a pastie.org of the generated html (Ctrl+U on the browser to check the html) and tell me where is the text which you need more margin on.